# Single Link Clustering in 2D ArrayList

Tags: hierarchical-clustering

Hi I am looking for a way to do Single Link Clustering with a 2D ArrayList in Java Netbeans.

Followed by visualizing the results on a graph.

As far as I know - LingPipe can do it but it uses a HashSet String which I think might display the results in accurately.

Any suggestions? I really appreciate the help. Thank you! :D